# How do I force ChatGPT API response to be brief while being brief myself?

Tags: chatgpt, api, chatgpt-3.5, nlp

For a hobby language learning tool, I use ChatGPT API to validate if a given sentence is grammatically correct. To save tokens, I want both the prompt and the response to be brief. But I can't make ChatGPT skip the unnecessary words without using many words myself.

Here's my prompt, structured as an API request with a `messages` object:

> **system**: Briefly point out grammatical errors in this sentence
>
> **user**: Han løber or singer, men Squidward ikke er glad for det.

Here's the response I'm getting:

> "Han løber or singer, men Squidward ikke er glad for det."
>
> The grammatical errors in the sentence are as follows:
>
> 1. "Han løber or singer," is incorrect. The word "or" should be replaced with "og" to mean "and" in English.
> 2. "Squidward ikke er glad for det." is incorrect. The word order should be rearranged to "Squidward er ikke glad for det."

Starting with repeating the sentence followed by *The grammatical errors in the sentence are as follows* is a waste of tokens. How do I make it just give me the errors, if any, or simply say "Correct" or "Yes" or something like that?

Comment: I couldn't get ChatGPT to produce correct results while doing this. ChatGPT couldn't correct the sentences properly. The output can get shorter if you tell ChatGPT to display only the errors. I could get it to display only the errors using "Present the errors in the sentence. Present the errors alone."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a wording didn't work as you expect try changing it. In this case the system prompt used was

> Briefly point out grammatical errors in this sentence

Try rewording the about using a direct and more technical tone. Below is an example using the [OpenAI playground](https://platform.openai.com). It shows a way to reword the system prompt using the same user prompt and depicting the assistant response

[image: Playground screenshot]

System

> Point out grammatical errors in this sentence using short sentences.

User

> Han løber or singer, men Squidward ikke er glad for det.

Assistant

> - "Han løber or singer" is incorrect. It should be "Han løber eller synger."
> - "men Squidward ikke er glad for det" should be "men Squidward er ikke glad for det."

As you can see, the system prompt length is very close to the original, and the response (Assistant) is shorter.

The parameters, model, temperature, maximum length, etc., used are the default parameters. You might play with these parameters to learn how they affect the API response.

If you are looking for an optimal cost-benefit, apply an "engineering" approach. This might be expensive at the beginning and might not be worth it for a hobby project.

References

- [GPT best practices](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt-best-practices).
  This document includes several tactics. I think you should read it thoroughly.

Comment: *“apply an "engineering" approach”* Could you please explain the method in the answer?

Comment: @A.L Please post a follow up question showing your efforts.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the OpenAI Playground – didn't know about it. I ended up dropping the requirement for the errors being pointed out and explained. I have posted my final approach in a separate answer. I will, however, accept your answer, because I don't mind. Thanks again for contributing to the conversation!

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Wicket suggested, I have naturally been rewording the prompt a lot, but it wasn't getting any better, at least not much.

No matter how I worded my prompt, the response would still always start with the sentence I gave as input.

It would then proceed pointing out the errors in my input. At some point I started getting these weird glitches, where it complained about things that weren't in my input. Or conversely, it would sometimes say I got something wrong, suggesting it should have been written… exactly how I wrote it.

Here's an example of both in one response:

> The word order in the phrase "noget fedt løn" is incorrect. In Danish, the adjective usually comes before the noun, so it should be "fedt løn" instead of "løn fedt."

Finally, it would close the response with the corrected version of the sentence, which seemed reasonable almost always – at least, to my limited Danish knowledge.

So I have finally realised that that's what I should ask for: the corrected sentence only:

> Check Danish grammar of this sentence. Accept absurdity. Reply only with the corrected sentence.

This solves the issue of it echoing the input back to me and using unnecessary words overall. It also removes the explanations which are sometimes contradictory or confusing.

Having the corrected sentence only should be enough, as a language learner very often understands the errors anyway once they are pointed out.